# name pattern regex

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to get a regex pattern for name where i m using for validation purpose.The pattern which i m using now is having some problem.The problem is if i give a single name like

```
jack morrison paul
```

its taking but if i give

```
jack  paul
```

where i am giving jack and double space and paul its not taking.jack is first name morrison is middle name and paul is last name.If i give first and last name and if i dont give middle name its taking double spaces while validating.I think some problem with my regex so please help me in solving this problem.I am new to this.

```
 //  regex pattern     
 ^([A-Za-z]([A-Za-z](\\s|\\.|_)*?)+[a-zA-Z]*$
```

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: José, Bjørn, Noël, etc. are not valid names?

Comment: @arkku : as per my requirements i doing.Whether people have different name pattern or rules i least bothered now.My client needs this so i need to give in that pattern

Comment: @Bart, good catch! `ˋunichars -a '\pL' '[^a-zA-Z]' | wc -lˋ == 12917`. That’s just a few of ’em, eh?! Basically, each and every time you see somebody write `A-Z`, it’s almost guaranteed that they’ve done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your question better. I had to read it multiple times to understand what you were trying to achieve.

My first stab:

```
^([\w]+)\s+([\s\w]+)\s+([\w]+)$
```

It will split first, middle, and last name.

Comment: Java has a 1960s idea of `\w` and `\s`, so that won’t work. Other languages aren’t broken which is probably why you forgot. You have to use properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
^(\w+)\s+(?:(\w+)\s+){0,1}(\w+){0,1}$
```

I simplified the name captures a bit by just using `\w`, which will match more than just letters, but you can change that out for your more specific requirements.

In the middle: `(?:(\w+)\s+){0,1}` says we're going to look for one or more word characters, and one or more spaces, as a group between 0 and 1 times, meaning it's optional.

But I think the part that was throwing you was the use of just single `\s`, which means it has to be one space exactly.  I used `\s+` meaning at least one space, but possibly more.  You can change this to be more limiting if you like, such as: `\s{1,2}` meaning between 1 and two spaces.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The `{0,1}` can be replaced by a `?`. (If I'm not mistaken)

Comment: You are correct, the OP seemed like a begginer so I thought the example I used was a little easier to understand.

Comment: Its really nice but its not working for me. two blank space between two names are not getting validated.

Comment: @yopirates When you say "validated" what do you mean?  Are you saying that your test case isn't matching?

Comment: validation is done in servlet for that i m using regex for name validation. if i done give middle name then error message is getting showed which i dont want.Even if we dont give middle name it should take

Comment: Are you sure you're copying it properly?  In my test cases, which included a first and last name separated by two spaces, it matched properly.  I noticed the sample you pasted included double backslashes, maybe when you copied mine you missed one of those?

Comment: in java we need to give double backslashes. I changed your code to double backslashes but still not working dont know why

Comment: You cannot use `\w` or `\s` in Java: they do not work properly.  And Java does not support a useful whitespace property either, so you have to rewrite that `\s` very uncomfortably: `[\t\n\v\f\r\x85\u2028\u2029\p{Zs}]`. Yeah, it sucks. At least you can use something like `[\pL\pN_]` in lieu of Java’s busted version of `\w`.